# WP_Query() Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object in ...single-diapers.php on line 82

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following very strait forward code, but it doesn't work. I have write queries like that many many times, but this time I am faced with a very strange problem.

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'diapers',
    'post_status'            => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'         => '3'
);

$products = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $products->have_posts() ) {

?>
<div class="more-products">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <h3 class="more-products-title text-center text-md-right">
            <?php
                _e('more products', 'z');
            ?>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
            <?php
                while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
                    $products->the_post();
            ?>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
```

But I am getting the following error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object in /var/www/projects/no-company/wp-content/themes/babies/single-diapers.php on line 82
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  234248  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0001  234696  require( '/project-path/wp-blog-header.php' )   .../index.php:17
3   0.0302  2471776 require_once( '/project-path/wp-includes/template-loader.php' ) .../wp-blog-header.php:16
4   0.0374  2594376 include( '/project-path/wp-content/themes/babies/single-diapers.php' )  .../template-loader.php:74
```

Is there anyone that can see something wrong with this code ? I have try, but I can't see anything that's wrong with this code.

In addition, you should know, that I have try to `print_r` the `$products` right before the `while ( $products->have_posts() )` and the `$products` contains data.

Also, I have try the `print_r` inside the loop, after the `$products->the_post()` and in the first loop I have normal the data inside the object, but in the second loop, I get as result a `0`.

Finally, I have also use the same code structure to another template file in my code and works, but this particular one doesn't wont to work :(

Comment: What does it gives if you try same thing by changing the name `$products` to `$the_query` ?

Comment: Let me try it and I will tell you

Comment: Continues with that same problem. Nothing change, and it seems that's right to have the same behavior :)

Comment: Strange ! This code resides in which file ?

Comment: i thing you need to create your file like a template. Right now your file is just as php file

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner I have it inside the `single-diapers.php` which is the single file for the custom post type.

Comment: @Lakhan do you mean to create an external file like `template-random-diapers.php` and call is with `get_template_part()`?

Comment: Same code works fine for me. What is your line number 74 in that file?

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner the `$products->have_posts()`. This code at the first loop is an object, but in the second loop becomes `0`. But just note, that I don't use any hook/filter and I have only one plugin activated, that's not posible to make that kind of problem

Comment: just add this in your top of the page :
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/

Comment: Make sure You have posted all essential code :)

Comment: just an fyi you don't need `'post_status' => 'publish'` it is the default so it is unnecessary here.

Comment: also which line is 82.. can you make a comment for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop the error message with the following (but it still does not solve the not an object problem).

```
if ( is_object($products) && $products->have_posts() ) {
```

This will mean that if the code fails like this for other people it will not give them a fatal error. However, you still need to find out why you do not have an object when you were expecting one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, but I cannot use it, as this just mute the problem, doesn't solve it.

Comment: I'd expect an error if the query produced no rows. It is better to inspect for problems and respond accordingly. Even if all you do is log it.